# Is it possible that one windows service is listening on multiple ports?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, port, rpc

I want to have a windows service which can listen coming request on more than one port. Is it possible ? if no then any workaround ?

Comment: services that you can see under services.msc consol on windows OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short, yes it is possible. You could use for example a network [socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on different ports.
Or own [CustomCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for windows services, which can be used to control a service remotely.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, Windows service can listen to more then one ports without any problem.